# Execute code only if condition matches and check for value in regular intervals in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have to execute some piece of code only `if` the value of some `variable` matches some value. Also I have to keep on checking for the value of the variable at regular intervals and even if after sometime(`maxWaitTime`), the value is not equal, then I have to stop checking for the value of the variable and send a message to the user.

My present code is as follows:

```
const intervalId = setInterval(function () {
  const localStorageArray = JSON.parse(
    localStorage.getItem('myArray') || '[]',
  );

  if (
    !localStorageArray ||
    (localStorageArray && localStorageArray[0] === myCurrentVal)
  ) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}, 1000);

// other code
```

Here the `other code` is getting executed without waiting for the `if` condition in `setInterval`. Is it because `setInterval` will not be in the call stack? Please correct me if I am wrong.
I have to execute the `other code` above inside the `if` condition of `setInterval` or else stop execution (be inside the interval) until the `maxWaitTime` is reached. How can I implement this?

Comment: if (!localStorageArray ) is never true so you can remove it. Try: `if (localStorageArray.findIndex(myCurrentVal) === 0)`

Comment: I assume that `localStorage` is being modified from another browser tab. As such, rather than polling storage, you'd be better off using a `storage` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event

Comment: I am using `storage` event to modify `localStorage`. My problem is only that the code below the `setInterval` is being executed directly without waiting for the `if` condition inside `setInterval`.

Comment: @Lax_Sam JS intervals don't block code execution, code after (outside) the interval will run immediately after the interval is defined (regardless of how long it will be before the function is run/how many times it is run)

Comment: @DBS Got it! So is there any way to block code execution until my if condition is reached or waited till `maxWaitTime` along with checking for variable value at 1 sec intervals?

Comment: You could always call another function inside the `if` statement that clears the interval.

Comment: @mplungjan It is not stopping the execution of `other code` until `if`. The code after `setInterval` is getting executed immediately.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.. The interval does not block anything,. You need to continue from INSIDE the interval

Comment: `if(...){ clearInterval(intervalId); doWhatEverNext(); }` Or a better solution is if you control what is ever setting localstorage to fire some sort of custom event.

Comment: See my update. I did not understand you wanted a "wait before continuing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (!localStorageArray)` is never true so you can remove it.

Try this

```js
let localStorageArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myArray') || '[]');
window.addEventListener('storage', (event) => { localStorageArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myArray') || '[]') });
const count = Math.max(maxWaitTime / 1000)
const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  const found = localStorageArray.findIndex(myCurrentVal) === 0;
  const done = --count <= 0;
  if (found || done) clearInterval(intervalId);
  if (found) processOtherCode();
  else alert('I give up');
}, 1000);
```